# Why the other URL is opening instead of the expected URL after clicking on a link received from google search in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, url, url-rewriting

I'm using Mozilla Firefox on my PC. When I search something using google a list of results get displayed, till then it functions properly. But when I right click or left click on any of the links from the results fetched, some other URL gets placed into the address bar of browser instead of the expected URL in a browser and a blank webpage gets appears. I'm not getting why this is happening.

Due to this I'm not able to open the search result by clicking on a hyperlink. Currently for opening the URL I've to copy the URL of the result link and paste it into the address bar. This long run process really irritates me. Can you help me in correcting this issue I'm having with firefox?

The URLs which frequently gets open are as follows:

```
http://www.ihavenet.com/?search=home+based+jobs+in+chennai&n=1380343306
http://www.ihavenet.com/?search=data+entry+projects&n=1380344121
```

and similar Other URLs gets placed in address bar.

Comment: try restoring firefox to default settings it might help you,sounds like a addon/extension issue,remove suspected addons

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc

Answer (score 1):

According to Google, the issue you are having is to do with malware installed as a by-product of installing toolbars.

The article [Remove Ihavenet.com redirect (Virus Removal Guide)](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/ihavenet-virus-removal/) provides a detailed guide on how you can remedy your problem. Just to be safe you should remove all of the installed tool bars and run a virus/malware scan afterwards (in safe mode).

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly the problem caused by the adware you unnoticingly installed on your system.You may use applications like [Spybot Search & Destroy](http://www.safer-networking.org/) or [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/products/malwarebytes_pro/) to remove malware from your system.

This article [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/2998/how-does-spyware-malware-or-crapware-get-on-my-computer/) explains a few ways in which you get these sorts of malware in your computer. This article [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/2875/remove-malware-quickly-with-malwarebytes-anti-malware/) illustrates how you can remove a malware from your computer using Malwarebytes Anti-Malware.You can always reinstall mozilla firefox or follow this [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/restore-the-default-settings-in-firefox-without-uninstalling-it/) to restore it to default settings.